# passing a function to map in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to render a blog post from my database. but I need to call a download image function for every item.

I've tried to put it in the .map function but in getting errors I'm not to sure how to go about it I pass the function as a prop to the component

```
  async function downloadImage(path) {
    try {
      setIsOpen(true);
      const { data, error } = await supabase.storage
        .from("public/job-photo")
        .download(`jobphotos/${path}.jpg`);
      if (error) {
        throw error;
      }
      const url = URL.createObjectURL(data);
      setAvatarUrl(url);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error downloading image: ", error.message);
    }
  }
```

comp

```
dataFetch.map((item) => (
            <div
              key={item.genid}
              className="flex flex-col rounded-lg shadow-lg overflow-hidden"
            

          {downloadImg(item.genid)}
          <div className="flex-shrink-0">
            <img className="h-48 w-full object-cover" src={img} alt="" />
          </div>
          <div className="flex-1 bg-white dark:bg-secondaryDark p-6 flex flex-col justify-between">
            <div className="flex-1">
              <p className="text-sm font-medium text-indigo-600 dark:text-white">
                {item.category}
              </p>

              <p className="text-xl font-semibold text-gray-900 dark:text-yellow-400">
                {item.jobname}
              </p>
              <p className="mt-3 text-base text-gray-500 dark:text-white">
                {item.jobdescription}
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
```

[image: erro image]

Comment: One of the errors will be calling `downloadImg` not `downloadImage`.

Comment: hello the question doesn't show it but it was passed as a prop as downloadImg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need another array state to store the downloaded images. Call `downloadImg` for all of the `dataFetch` items on mount, and only try to render the image after the same index in the images array isn't undefined. Something along the lines of:

```
// Better designed download function that resolves with the downloaded data:
function downloadImage(path) {
    return supabase.storage
        .from("public/job-photo")
        .download(`jobphotos/${path}.jpg`)
        .then(({ data, error }) => {
            if (error) throw error;
            return URL.createObjectURL(data);
        });
}
```

```
const [urls, setUrls] = useState(() => dataFetch.map(() => null));
// Fetch all URLS when the component mounts:
useEffect(() => {
  dataFetch.forEach((item, i) => {
    downloadImage(item.genid).then((url) => {
      setUrls(urls => urls.map((prev, j) => j === i ? url : prev);
    }); // .catch(handleError);
  });
}, []);
```

```
// Render them once they exist:
dataFetch.map((item, i) => (
    <div
        key={item.genid}
        className="flex flex-col rounded-lg shadow-lg overflow-hidden"
    >
        { urls[i] ? <img src={urls[i] /} : null }
```

Comment: hello it seems to have some sort of error in this method It only renders 1 picture and sets the other to null

Comment: added photo to post

Comment: Ops, change `setUrls` to a callback

Comment: inside download img?

Comment: No, when you call `setUrls` - just like the code in my answer